# pdo catch and output mysql errors

Tags: php, pdo, try-catch

I have an insert statement that is executed with PDO. Insert works great however if there is an error I would like it displayed to the user.

I have the below try-catch block.

```
try{ 
    $insertuser = $db->prepare('INSERT INTO `she_she`.`Persons` (`idnumber`,`addedby`,`firstname`, `middlename`, `surname`, `fullname`, `gender`, `birthdate`, `homelanguage`, `department`, `employeetype`, `employeestatus`) VALUES  (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)'); 
    $insertuser->execute(array($idnumber,$user,$firstname, $middlename, $surname, $fullname, $gender, $birthdate, $language, $department, $employmenttype, $personstatus));  
} 
catch(PDOException $exception){ 
    return $exception; 
}
```

If the query fails, or let's say a duplicate IDNumber, I want this displayed to the user.

If I simply try to echo the variable $exception it does not work.

I want to return the MySQL error to the user.

Comment: $exception will be an object of the type PDOException, and two of its many attributes will be the mysql error code and error message.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

By default PDO is not in a state that will display errors. you need to provide the following in your DB connection

```
$dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
```

More info can be seen [Here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.setattribute.php)

Comment: Thanks. If I set error mode to `ERRMODE_WARNING` it returns the warning on top of the page, how can I set it to the value of the variable and return this where I want to on the page. Thanks

Comment: In your catch block you can set $exception to a different variable for use later.

    `catch(PDOException $exception){ 
       $error = $exception->getMessage(); 
    }

    //later in code
    echo "An Error has occurred " . $error;`

or something similar.

Answer (score 4):

1.Add ERRMODE_EXCEPTION mode after your db connection:

```
$dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
```

2.And than you must use try{} catch{} method for all your mysql query. Like this:

```
try {
    $SQL = "DELETE FROM items WHERE item_id=:item_id";
    $m = $dbh->prepare($SQL);
    $m->bindParam(':item_id', $item_id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $m->execute();
    //success
    $return = "Your success message.";
}
catch (PDOException $e) {
    //error
    $return = "Your fail message: " . $e->getMessage();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use this:

```php
return $exception->getMessage();
```

See the page on the documentation of Exception class:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/exception.getmessage.php